# git difftool not recognize current file path

Tags: git, araxis

I did *git difftool FORMER_BRANCH_NAME HEAD* and. expect I could compare files in Araxis merge.

However, the  Araxis merge are displaying files in temporary file paths.

*/var/folders/ft/d77t_nxd141g373d7p6t47lc0000gn/T/uga8V8_XXXXller.js*

I don't expect this for the files with my latest commit. It should be **/src/views/a.js**

This kind of file path which could let me make the changes back to the file directly.

How could I achieve this? Make the **Araxis merge**  recognizes the real file path and do the compare.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD` refers to a commit, not to the working tree, so the files involved in its diff might not be the same as/exist in the working tree, or remain that way.

You can diff against the working tree by specifying only one commit:

```
git difftool FORMER_BRANCH_NAME
```